# Dynamic created widget id value of multi-instance in jQuery

Tags: widgets

I'm new to Wordpress development and I'm building a new widgets with image uploader, its working fine when i have only one instance of a widget but when i add more they start to interfere with each ,  i understand that if i can somehow can get the the value of `echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img1') );` in jquery I can solve the problem but i'm stuck , here is the widget form code

```
<p>
    <button
        class="img1_header_widget"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img1') ); ?>"
    >
        <?php esc_attr_e( 'First image', 'starter' ); ?>
    </button>
    <input
        class="widefat profile-pic1"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img1') ); ?>"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name('img1') ); ?>"
        type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $img1 ); ?>"
    >
    <img
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img1') ); ?>"
        src="<?php echo esc_attr( $img1 ); ?>" height="150" width="150"
        class="img1_header_widget_preview"
    >
</p>
<!-- $img2 input -->
<p>
    <button
        class="img2_header_widget"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img2') ); ?>"
    >
        <?php esc_attr_e( 'Seconde image', 'starter' ); ?>
    </button>
    <input
        class="widefat profile-pic2"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img2') ); ?>"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name('img2') ); ?>"
        type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $img2 ); ?>"
    >
    <img
        src="<?php echo esc_attr( $img2 ); ?>" height="150" width="150"
        class="img2_header_widget_preview"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img2') ); ?>"
    >
</p>
<!-- $img3 input -->
<p>
    <button
        class="img3_header_widget"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img3') ); ?>"
    >
        <?php esc_attr_e( 'Seconde image', 'starter' ); ?>
    </button>
    <input
        class="widefat profile-pic3"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img3') ); ?>"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name('img3') ); ?>"
        type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $img3 ); ?>"
    >
    <img
        src="<?php echo esc_attr( $img3 ); ?>" height="150" width="150"
        class="img3_header_widget_preview"
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('img3') ); ?>"
    >
</p>
```

and here is the js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.img1_header_widget').live("click", function( e ){

        e.preventDefault();

        var imageUploader = wp.media({
            'title' : 'Upload image 1',
            'button' : {
                'text': 'set the image'
            },
            'multiple' : false
        });

        imageUploader.open();

        imageUploader.on("select", function(){
            var image = imageUploader.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();
            var link = image.url;


            $("input.profile-pic1").val(link).trigger('change');

            $("img.img1_header_widget_preview").attr('src',link);

        });

    });
    $('button.img2_header_widget').live("click", function( e ){

        e.preventDefault();

        var imageUploader = wp.media({
            'title' : 'Upload image 2',
            'button' : {
                'text': 'set the image'
            },
            'multiple' : false
        });

        imageUploader.open();

        imageUploader.on("select", function(){
            var image = imageUploader.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();
            var link = image.url;

            $("input.profile-pic2").val(link).trigger('change');


            $("img.img2_header_widget_preview").attr('src',link);
        });

    });
    $('button.img3_header_widget').live("click", function( e ){

        e.preventDefault();

        var imageUploader = wp.media({
            'title' : 'Upload image 3',
            'button' : {
                'text': 'set the image'
            },
            'multiple' : false
        });

        imageUploader.open();

        imageUploader.on("select", function(){
            var image = imageUploader.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();
            var link = image.url;

            $("input.profile-pic3").val(link).trigger('change');

            $("img.img3_header_widget_preview").attr('src',link);
        });

    });
});
```

I even tried to pass the value using `wp_localize_script` but for some reason I end up with `widget-starter_header_widget--img1` instead of the `widget-starter_header_widget-15-img1`.

Comment: helppppppppp ???